# Check fields of Json that are incorrect on .net endpoint

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core

**Context**

I have the following endpoint:

```
[HttpPatch("sendForm")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SendFormResponseDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult?> SendForm([FromBody] UpdateFormRequest updateFormRequest)
    => Ok(await _sendForm.InvokeAsync(updateFormRequest));
```

`UpdateFormRequest` has a structure as follows:

```
public class UpdateFormRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public string? Val1 { get; set; }
    public string? Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Current result**

The endpoint is expecting a Json with the structure of `updateFormRequest`, which. When the input json is not correct, it returns the error that updateFormRequest was expected.

**Expected result**

I want that whenever the input json is incorrect, it tells which fields are missing or they have incorrect input format (for example, an integer instead of an string). Is there any way to achieve this without having to manually check each of the input fields of the json?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You can select all the errors from `ModelState` and return it.

```
public class UpdateFormRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controllers**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        public IActionResult SendForm(UpdateFormRequest updateFormRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                           .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                           .ToList();
                return BadRequest(errors);
            }
            return  Ok(updateFormRequest);
        }
```

Now when I send invalid json to endpoint, It will return all the error message automatically.

[image]

Of Course you can format your response.